# React Ant Design styles not loading

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using webpack 4x and trying to include [antd](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design) along with `babel-plugin-import`.  I've updated my webpack config to use:

```js
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      include: [/[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*antd/],
      use: [
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            modifyVars: { '@primary-color': '#1DA57A' },
            javascriptEnabled: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

This works, as in it doesn't throw any errors.  However, the styles don't seem to be showing up in the actual app.  I'm including like this:

```js
import { Button } from 'antd'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
  }
}
```

It's rendering the button just fine, it's just the styles that aren't coming in.  Any idea if there's something else that needs to be done so the styles are actually included?  Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

you need to import the less file of antd in less :

```
//main.less
@import "~antd/dist/antd.less";
```

then import this file in ts/js index:

```
import './less/main.less';
```

you can also add the theme [config file](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less) in main.less

This is the webpack config I use (webpack3):

```
,{
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'theme.css'
                    }
                },{
                    loader: 'less-loader',
                    options: { javascriptEnabled: true }// compiles Less to CSS
                }]
          },
```

Comment: Hm, so that loads those basic styles, but still doesn't seem to be loading the component styles from Button.

Comment: Actually looks like adding `style-loader` and `css-loader` before the `less-loader` did the trick.

Comment: I added the webpack config that i used.

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution [here](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import/issues/313#issuecomment-563875877):

> In your index.js file, you can import ant style files:
> import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
> Reference: https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started